# jQuery fancy fields plugin select list

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using the fancy fields plugin found at http://www.jqfancyfields.com/ to style my select lists for a search form. The text boxes in the form are showing up in the URL, but the select values aren't. There's some code on the examples on the plugin site about binding something, but I really don't know jQuery and where to put everything. I'm also wanting to use a custom scrollbar, which the plugin does, but that also won't activate.

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myForm').fancyfields({customScrollBar:true});
      $('#myForm').fancyfields("bind","onSelectChange", function (input,text,val){
      });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<select id="myForm" name="type">
    <option value="">-select-</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```